# Any pitfalls in code for Restricting TextArea Length using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have to restrict length of a TextArea to 2 characters. I have found tons of answers. Reading those answers I have reached the following code.  It has event handlers for 'keydown' and 'keyup'.

1. Do you think this is correct and enough?
2. Will it work in all major browsers?

http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/VAYze/1/

1. Note: I don’t need a error message to display. Hence regular expression validation will not be good option for me.
2. Note: I am looking answer based on existing code – not a whole new answer
3. Note: Key Codes are referred from http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html and http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html

**UPDATE**

To handle text `dragged` into text area, I don't see a jQuery solution. I am planning to do a `regular expression validator` with `EnableClientScript`="false". It will validate in the server side only.This is to handle anything bypassed the existing jQuery operation.  [ASP Regular Expression Validator for Multi-line textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094997/asp-regular-expression-validator-for-multi-line-textbox)

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {


var maxLength = 2;

$('.multiline').keydown(function (e) {


    var existingText = $(this).val();
    var existingLength = existingText.length;

    if (existingLength >= maxLength) 
    {
        if (maxLength > 0) 
        {

            if (!checkSpecialKeys(e)) 
            {
                $(this).val(existingText.substring(0, maxLength));
                 $(this).css('color','red');

                //Newly entered character not rendered since false is returned
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }

  });


//To trim the text if a paste happens
$('.multiline').keyup(function (e) {

    var newText = $(this).val();
    var newLength = newText.length;

    if (newLength > maxLength) {
        if (maxLength > 0) {
            $(this).val(newText.substring(0, maxLength));
            $(this).css('color','red');
        }
    }

});


}
);


function checkSpecialKeys(e) 
{
if (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 90) 
{
    return false;
}

if (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 111) 
{
    return false;
}

else 
{
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Values of inputs and textareas can be filled by literally dragging a selected text inside them. Don't forget that possibility.

Comment: Why don't you use the maxlenght attribute?

Comment: It eventually needs to lose focus so you might want to attach a **change** event, which obviously would fire: `$('.multiline').change(function(){console.log('changed!')})`

Comment: There are trivial `dragover`, `dragenter` and `drop` event listeners but I wouldn stick with the `change` event since not all of these are supported by all the browsers whereas `change` AFAIK will trigger no matter what.

Comment: @inhan I have chnaged "keyup" with "change" event. I think, that is the only change the you suggest.

Comment: @Lijo no no my suggesion was an addition, not a change. Keep your key events, just add a separate event listener for the change event.

Comment: @inhan Thanks..Unfortunately change is not firing in IE8 with IE7 mode. Works fine in Firefox

Comment: So `<textarea class="multiline" onchange="console.log('changed)"></textarea>` does not do anything in IE7? Sorry I'm using a Mac so I can't test it myself. Also, check the `input` and `propertychange` event handlers. I just read about them [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338592/jquery-textarea-change-event) and [also here](http://api.jquery.com/change/#comment-66879816).

Answer (score 1):

<strike>From you requirments, I can only say you should use the maxlength attribute on your textarea. This saves you your JavaScript code, takes care of special scenarios, like dragging text into the the input.
Also it is faster since it is a browser function. 
It's supported by all browsers which support textarea.</strike>

Example:

```
<textarea maxlength="2"></textarea>
```

maxlength is a new property for for the textarea. It is not supporetd in all browsers... ([Source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp))

Sorry

Comment: I don't think it works in `IE8`. Did you try it in IE8? http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/VAYze/2/