# WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive)

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio, word-count

I'm building a web application using Visual Studio 2012. 
I'm attempting to add word count into my textbox. 
However after adding the the javascript codes and the html codes. I receive the error as stated above.

Here is my javascript codeds

Code :

```
function validateLimit(obj, divID, maxchar) {

objDiv = get_object(divID);

if (this.id) obj = this;

var remaningChar = maxchar - trimEnter(obj.value).length;

if (objDiv.id) {
    objDiv.innerHTML = remaningChar + " characters left";
}
if (remaningChar <= 0) {
    obj.value = obj.value.substring(maxchar, 0);
    if (objDiv.id) {
        objDiv.innerHTML = "0 characters left";
    }
    return false;
}
else
{ return true; }
}

function get_object(id) {
var object = null;
if (document.layers) {
    object = document.layers[id];
} else if (document.all) {
    object = document.all[id];
} else if (document.getElementById) {
    object = document.getElementById(id);
}
return object;
}

function trimEnter(dataStr) {
return dataStr.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "");
}
```

Server codes in master page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/JScript.js" ></script>
```

ASPX codes, ( Html codes )

```
<tr>
<th style="width: 595px; height: 135px;">Official Report :</th>
<td colspan="4" style="height: 135px">
  <asp:TextBox ID="tbofficial" runat="server" Height="121px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="878px" MaxLength="500"   ToolTip="Summary:(500 characters)" onkeyup="return validateLimit(this, 'lblMsg1', 500)" ></asp:TextBox>
  <div id="lblMsg1">500 characters left</div>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="tbofficial" Display="Dynamic" 
        SetFocusOnError="True">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
  <br />
  <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
  <br />
  <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
  <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="btnClear_Click" />
        </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 625, accepted):

You need a web.config key to enable the pre-4.5 validation mode.

More Info on **[ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh975440(v=vs.120))**:

> - ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode
>
> Specifies how ASP.NET globally enables the built-in validator controls
> to use unobtrusive JavaScript for client-side validation logic.
>
> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | Type: | [UnobtrusiveValidationMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.unobtrusivevalidationmode?view=netframework-4.8.1&redirectedfrom=MSDN) |
> | Default value: | None |
> | Remarks: | If this key value is set to "None" [default], the ASP.NET application will use the pre-4.5 behavior (JavaScript inline in the pages) for client-side validation logic. If this key value is set to "WebForms", ASP.NET uses HTML5 data-attributes and late bound JavaScript from an added script reference for client-side validation logic. |
> | Example: | ``` <appSettings> <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" /> </appSettings> ``` |

Comment: It seems "None" is **not** the default if you are using `targetFramework="4.5"`. I had to explicitly add this setting to my web.config for it to work.

Comment: Reminder: <appSettings> parent in the web.Config file should be the root element, that is <configuration>.

Answer (score 181):

Rather than disabling a new feature, I opted to follow the instructions of the error. In my global.asax.cs I added:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string JQueryVer = "1.7.1";
    ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition
    {
        Path = "~/Scripts/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".min.js",
        DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".js",
        CdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".min.js",
        CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".js",
        CdnSupportsSecureConnection = true,
        LoadSuccessExpression = "window.jQuery"
    });
}
```

This comes from an [msdn blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-4-5-scriptmanager-improvements-in-webforms/) which highlights some of the advantages of script resource mappings.  Of particular interest to me was centralized control over the delivery of the script files based on "debug=true", EnableCDN, etc.

Comment: @b_levitt I am kind a new to the .NET and came through the solution you mentioned. It indeed helped a lot but just curious how can I call the jQuery function. For example, I have a jQuery menu and after implementing the above method I am using `<script type='text/javascript'> //<![CDATA[ $(document).ready(function () { $("#menu").menu(); }) //]] </script>`. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Created a gist: https://gist.github.com/monoman/ca42e54cdac25ef2284b improving by not hardcoding the jQueryVer value;

Comment: NOTE: I added these two Nuget packages and things went smooth. had to copy new files in /bin folder to production server..https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery

Comment: Depends on your use case which one is correct. Our app has no validation whatsoever (purely content delivery) and we preferred turning it all off.

Answer (score 104):

There are at least three ways to disable the use of unobtrusive JavaScript for client-side validation:

1. Add the following to the web.config file:

   ```
   <configuration>
     <appSettings>
       <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
     </appSettings>
   </configuration>
   ```
2. Set the value of the `System.Web.UI.ValidationSettings.UnobtrusiveValidationMode` static property to `System.Web.UI.UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None`
3. Set the value of the `System.Web.UI.Page.UnobtrusiveValidationMode` instance property to `System.Web.UI.UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None`

To disable the functionality on a per page basis, I prefer to set the `Page.UnobtrusiveValidationMode` property using the page directive:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" UnobtrusiveValidationMode="None" %>
```

Comment: Nice call on the per-page setting.

Answer (score 48):

Unobtrusive validation is enabled by default in new version of ASP.NET.  Unobtrusive validation aims to decrease the page size by replacing the inline JavaScript for performing validation with a small JavaScript library that uses jQuery.

You can either disable it by editing web.config to include the following:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

Or better yet properly configure it by modifying the Application_Start method in global.asax:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
    ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery",
        new ScriptResourceDefinition
        {
            Path = "/~Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"
        }
    );
}
```

Page 399 of Beginning ASP.NET 4.5.1 in C# and VB provides a discussion on the benefit of unobtrusive validation and a walkthrough for configuring it.

For those looking for RouteConfig.  It is added automatically when you make a new project in visual studio to the App_Code folder.  The contents look something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls;

namespace @default
{
    public static class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
            settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
            routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does RouteConfig come from?

Comment: @Lucas When you create a new project with visual studio it adds RouteConfig.cs to the App_Code folder.  See edited answer.

Comment: Is this for MVC projects only? Doesn't seem to work for Web Sites (which do not have a project file) (WebForms)

Comment: @user0474975 Sorry I do not recall and don't have an environment to test on at the moment, but I would expect it to work same.

Comment: @denver I figured it out. It works in a WebSite/WebForms site by just removing the line "RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);" and declaring the ScriptResourceDefinition object on the line above, rather than directly in the AddDefinition method declaration. However, your answer pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 15):

to add a little more to the answer from b_levitt...
on global.asax:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace LoginPage
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string JQueryVer = "1.11.3";
            ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition
            {
                Path = "~/js/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".min.js",
                DebugPath = "~/js/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".js",
                CdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".min.js",
                CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".js",
                CdnSupportsSecureConnection = true,
                LoadSuccessExpression = "window.jQuery"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

on your default.aspx

```
<body>
   <form id="UserSectionForm" runat="server">
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">
          <Scripts>
               <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
          </Scripts>
     </asp:ScriptManager>
     <%--rest of your markup goes here--%>         
   </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 14):

I believe I have encountered the same quandary. I started encountering the problem when I changed to:

```
</system.web>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
```

Which gives the error message you describe above.

adding:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
```

Solves the issue, **but then it makes your validation controls/scripts throw Javascript runtime errors.**
If you change to:

```
</system.web>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0"/>
```

You should be OK, **but you’ll have to make sure the rest of your code does/ behaves as desired. You might also have to forgo some new features only available in 4.5 onward.**

**P.S. It is highly recommended that you read the following before implementing this solution. Especially, if you use Async functionality:**

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/

**UPDATE April 2017:**
After some some experimentation and testing I have come up with a combination that works:

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
```

with:

> jQuery version 1.11.3

Answer (score 6):

The problem occurred due to the Control validator. Just Add the J Query reference to your web page as follows and then add the Validation Settings in your web.config file to overcome the problem. I too faced the same problem and the below gave the solution to my problem.

**Step1:**

[image: Code to be added in web page]

**Step2 :**

[image: Code to be added in Web.config file]

It will resolve your problem.

Comment: Why should you add Jquery after setting UnobtrusiveValidationMode to none?

Answer (score 0):

It has 3 solutions that other guys told upper...
but when try Application_Start solution, My other jQuery library like Pickup_Date_and_Time doesn't work...
so I test second way and it's answered: 
1- set the Target FrameWork to Pre 4.5
2- Use  " UnobtrusiveValidationMode="None" " in your page header =>

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Master/MasteOfHotel.Master" 
    UnobtrusiveValidationMode="None" %>
```

it works for me and doesn't disrupt my other jQuery function.