# ASP.Net how to remove automatic jquery reference?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, controls

I'm already statically linking jQuery in my site master, but when I add certain built-in ASP controls (like validators), ASP automatically adds a second script reference (which then breaks things).

Example:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
 ControlToValidate="UserName" CssClass="field-validation-error" 
 ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." ForeColor="Red" />
```

Causes this to appear in the HTML:

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How do I remove this automatic reference?

Comment: Your question is too general, please be more specific, what controls are you add ? Which company made that controls, some code and links will help - and probably controls have some attributes to handle that! For example, I have link the jQuery statically on my master page, and have a lot of controls, but none of them add second jQuery link

Comment: @Aristos added example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [old jquery version is automatically included in asp.net webforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523745/old-jquery-version-is-automatically-included-in-asp-net-webforms)

Answer (score 2):

Old question but ran into this problem today when converting old project to framework 4.6.2. I had already added jQuery-reference to my masterpage and ASP.Net decided to add it again.

I was able to find a "fix" though I'm not sure why this fixes the problem. Maybe somebody can shed some light on this later on.

By default new web application project created with framework 4.6.2 will add the following line in Web.Config:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" />
```

Removing the line or even the **targetFramework-attribute** will result in ASP.Net not adding jQuery automatically anymore.

Comment: I know it's an old question.. but I'm hoping someone may have solved this!? I'm making changes to a legacy Web Forms app and coming up against this issue. Removing the targetFramework from the web.config fixes the jquery automatic reference, but breaks some other signalr features.. so it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Chris Have you checked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523745/old-jquery-version-is-automatically-included-in-asp-net-webforms/40511131

Comment: Thanks for the link @Esko, I followed the trail and eventually found that disabling the UnobtrusiveValidationMode worked for my project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660900/webforms-unobtrusivevalidationmode-requires-a-scriptresourcemapping-for-jquery