# old jquery version is automatically included in asp.net webforms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a asp.net c# webforms project. In the output html in the div "aspNetHidden" is a link to

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I cannot figure out how to remove this code. It's not in the master page file, and I can't seem to find it anywhere. I would like to use a newer version of jquery, and place the reference at the bottom of the page instead.

I suspect it's from one of the installed NuGet packages, but I can't figure out which one, and I think i need them all.

EDIT:
If i create a new project and select ASP.NET Web Forms Application, the jquery link is there. I'm using visual studio express 2012.

EDIT 2: Found a solution - posted as an answer for others with similar problem to see.

Comment: Have you done a solution-wide search for jquery-1.8.2.js?

Comment: Are the page's content stored in database? Does your site publicly available?

Comment: Nope - just master pages and web forms. The site is not published yet, but the link to jquery occurs if I create a new project from scratch, and select "ASP.NET Web Forms Application"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. It's added by the scriptmanager, but can be overridden by adding the following in the global.asax. I don't know if I can disable it completely, but this works for me.

```
string str = "1.10.2";
        ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition
        {
            Path = "~/js/jquery-" + str + ".min.js",
            DebugPath = "~/js/jquery-" + str + ".min.js",
            CdnPath = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-" + str + ".min.js",
            CdnDebugPath = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-" + str + ".min.js",
            CdnSupportsSecureConnection = true
        });
```

Comment: You can certainly disable it, remove the reference in your master page :) I prefer bundling over this method, myself.

Comment: I have no reference in my master page. I deleted the entire scriptsmanager from the master, but it gets included anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by change version of jquery in **packages.config**

change

```
  <package id="AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery" version="1.8.2" targetFramework="net45" />
 <package id="jQuery" version="1.8.2" targetFramework="net45" />
```

to

```
<package id="AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery" version="2.1.4" targetFramework="net45" />
 <package id="jQuery" version="2.1.4" targetFramework="net45" />
```

my jquery version is **2.1.4**