# jQuery 1.10.2 is added automatically in asp.net master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, webforms

In my asp.net web forms master page for some reason jQuery 1.10.2 is automatically added, please check the screenshot:

[image]

Clicking on the script opens up the JS file although no file exists in that folder.

No reference is found to that JS file, I'm not sure from where does the JS file comes.

Comment: Can we see your master page source?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8pum1GEj @n8wrl

Comment: probably registered in your bundles

Comment: no bundling is happening @charlietfl

Comment: Ok now post Site.master.cs

Comment: The Pastebin link on which this question relies is now 404, which makes this question closable. Please always include code in the question itself, rather than supplying external links.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Simon Larson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523745/old-jquery-version-is-automatically-included-in-asp-net-webforms)

or better still an example below

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
   ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", 
        new  ScriptResourceDefinition {
             Path = "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js",
             DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js",
             CdnPath = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js",
             CdnDebugPath = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js",
             CdnSupportsSecureConnection = true,
             LoadSuccessExpression = "window.jQuery"
          });
     }
```

You can change the version number to suit the one you use.