# CausesValidation=true not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have used a Requiredfieldvalidator to validate a text field however when I click on button the page gets posted back even if validation fails. What am i doing wrong? Below is my code.

```
<div id="addFactDiv" style="display:none;">
     <asp:TextBox ID="inputFact" Height="50px" Width="100%" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" placeholder="Enter a fact"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:requiredfieldvalidator CssClass="validator" Display="Dynamic" ID="Requiredfieldvalidator5" ControlToValidate="inputFact" ValidationGroup="ValidateFact" ErrorMessage="Please Enter a fact" runat="server"/>
     <input type="button" Class="cancel" value="Cancel" OnClick="hideInput('addFactDiv');" />
     <asp:Button ID="Submit_Fact" CssClass="submit" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="ValidateFact" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Fact_Click"/>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I had some commented out fields as well on the page causing the two errors I have mentioned in comments. When I removed those fields it started working fine. However I am not sure why.. Do commented out fields also get rendered on the page the same way as others?

Comment: check if you have any jquery error on your page in console of browser.

Comment: Check the Submit_Fact_Click method, it may be throwing a javascript error.

Comment: @Shashank I am getting these two errors: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'controltovalidate' of null country-guide.aspx?Country=Anguilla&City=The+Valley:362
(anonymous function)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'evaluationfunction' of null WebResource.axd?d=x2nkrMJGXkMELz33nwnakImgmOWJ-SIqKoPuh1nH8njgfYOD-km8FhKtXcG6E3ZBrFMQnBeIhF6x--KmR…:281
ValidatorOnLoad WebResource.axd?d=x2nkrMJGXkMELz33nwnakImgmOWJ-SIqKoPuh1nH8njgfYOD-km8FhKtXcG6E3ZBrFMQnBeIhF6x--KmR…:281
(anonymous function)

What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

I tried on my sample application and found below error,

*WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).*

Later I found that we need to add below key in .config file, which fixed the issue. (I am not sure why!)

Ref: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660900/webforms-unobtrusivevalidationmode-requires-a-scriptresourcemapping-for-jquery)

**My aspx code looks like below,**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="addFactDiv" style="float: right">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="test" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"             ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ValidationGroup="test"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </p>
</form>
```

Hope this might help!!