# WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

my Problem is quite simple: "Someone" changed "Something" on the IIS in order to make another Website work.
But now, I get the error on our Application:

```
WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).
```

The problem is: This Application is for testing-purposes and should be running on the same Configs etc. as on the Customer side. It seems like this problem can be fixed by changing the config: [WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660900/webforms-unobtrusivevalidationmode-requires-a-scriptresourcemapping-for-jquery) but as said, I'd not like to do that.

My question: What can cause this problem? The Default Web Site is running under the Classic.net AppPool, which means .Net2 and Managed PipeLine=Classic. The Website, which causes this problem is running under .Net4 Integrated, but so does it on the Customers side.

Thanks in advance for all Feedback.

Matthias

Edith: I guess the problem was the Update to 4.5. Microsoft invented this ValidationMode for HTML 5 but did NOT set the Standard-Value to None. So I have to change every config to set it manually...

Comment: i faced the same problem when i tried to use AJAX Control Toolkit are you using it?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question, as I had the same problem occur to me today.  I was puzzled however, trying to figure out who Edith was, and why you were addressing her in your question.  That is, until it occurred to me that you're a native German speaker, and you meant to write "Edit:".  My wife, who is a native German speaker, frequently spells English words ending with "t" as ending with "th", too!

Comment: Does anyone know what might have actually been changed in IIS to now cause this issue?  Throughout the web, this error is answered with the standard "add this line to the AppSettings".  I have many servers running this application without issue and 1 server that now display this error message.  I'd rather know what was changed in IIS to cause this to appear on the 1 server.  Any ideas where to look?  Did you find what was changed for another site that cause yours to display this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you have to add this in your Web.config

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Yep, as as said in my Edith. I still don't understand why Microsoft does not make the standard-value to none. Whatever, case solved.