# Bootstrap Select Not Working With Asp.Net Validators

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3 select plugin to make my dropdownlists more fancy. It works perfectly until I add a simple `RequiredFieldValidator` to the page for ANOTHER control such as a textbox. All beautiful dropdowns are then changed to typical dropdowns.

Here is my HTML:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategories" runat="server" CssClass="show-menu-arrow selectpicker" DataSourceID="dsCategories" DataTextField="CategoryName" DataValueField="CategoryID">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And the JS:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    });
});
```

I know Asp.Net validators add some Javascript code to the page, and I guess they are causing some conflict. I also used `$.noConflict()` with no success.

I need to know how to solve this problem.

Edit:

The rendered markup is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title>
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
    <link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).on('load', function () {
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Test2.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="Lu54Lc5gUoMcES3FS5vAFbfEDc2WKzPnEz29Y/3ecH2fPQjmLCl030G8zXJfv035qxsI7TaEKDLL7vpb2xD61vH7RnpFzze8sAOGlMFp+Vw=" />
</div>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=x2nkrMJGXkMELz33nwnakDs9KKDZZn2GO2GOnzQ8bhnAg5hg1uDK_xxs2F4qGzZL4suzNGfgwk1f_Kqd7w6GL2Mz9JWbGv_Uo50eVnuTPU81&amp;t=634773918900000000" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
if (typeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) return false;
return true;
}
//]]>
</script>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="vRZe0MAmYSmodYTkQXHZO1ZKY9EsMANgK1GXMQfTQ/Lke9yD8gU8jV56OwuAerfGHV5FTQnt+m2zQwARykzPYNpaD2HUK+lPDeGfKZazORSavMSQXAZHoeLR8Yzltk+3oS5ytg9B7n2ikrVh+v5DI1Ags0aEZzExyTTjsOFgBxOaBU8PcHXOyE/7XMK3TTOx" />
</div>
    <div>
        <select name="DropDownList1" id="DropDownList1" class="show-menu-arrow selectpicker">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>

</select>
    <input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" />
    <span data-val-controltovalidate="TextBox1" data-val-errormessage="RequiredFieldValidator" id="RequiredFieldValidator1" data-val="true" data-val-evaluationfunction="RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid" data-val-initialvalue="" style="visibility:hidden;">RequiredFieldValidator</span>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: define "not working" you any have errors in console ?

Comment: You need to provide more information, but my initial guess would be to add `CausesValidation="false"` to the DropDownList

Comment: Show the rendered markup.

Comment: @Khan, It is already set to false.

Comment: @johnSmith, "not working" means that dropdownlists change from bootstrap style to normal style. In the console, there is an error that reads "TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function". But would adding a simple validator cause this?

Comment: @CarrieKendall, The rendered markup is added.

Comment: @Delphi.Boy Can you copy the generated WebResource.axd file into pastebin and link here? My guess is there is something in that file that is overwriting your jQuery object. Maybe another component is trying to use its own jQuery and without the requiredfieldvalidator there is no need for WebResource.axd?

Comment: @Khan, Here you go: http://pastebin.com/30BFvSBM

Comment: Can you link to the place where we can get the plugin? Can we get it directly from nuget?

Comment: @deostroll, Here is the plugin page: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer! When I first used a validator on a page in this project, I got an error : "WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'."

I googled and on [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660900/webforms-unobtrusivevalidationmode-requires-a-scriptresourcemapping-for-jquery), I found 2 solutions. One suggested disabling a new feature of ASP.Net 4.5, and another one suggested adding some code to properly configure it.

I took the latter (adding `ScriptResourceMapping` to `Application_Start`). And I faced this problem somewhere else in my project.

After a few days of struggling and not getting an answer here, I suddenly realized that it might be the cause of the problem.

So I changed my codes, and added some key to Web.config and it works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

i think you were on the right way with no conflict version of your implemented jQuery.

Please try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(window).on('load', function () {
        jQuery('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try calling all the Bootstrap related scripts at the end of the page