# Error when perform validation on ASP .Net textbox

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am adding a new ASP .Net empty Web page. I've added one textbox, on it I've tried to perform validations for required field validator. But when I execute them I got this error:

```
WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).
```

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660900/webforms-unobtrusivevalidationmode-requires-a-scriptresourcemapping-for-jquery

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
 <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" 
value="WebForms" />
```

from your webconfig file
or add

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
```

to webconfig

also you can check stackoverflow discussions about this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660900/webforms-unobtrusivevalidationmode-requires-a-scriptresourcemapping-for-jquery)