# RegularExpressionValidator does not work in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to set MaxLength property of a textbox with multiline in asp.net(for example 100 character).
I do not want to use javascript solution. I have used :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>                        
      <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z.]{0,100}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="109px" Width="274px"  ></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

and this :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>                        
      <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rgConclusionValidator2"                   ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,100}$" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" /></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="109px" Width="274px"  ></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

but none of them works. i have test on latest ie, firefox , chrome , opera.
thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* working, but:

1. Validators won't validate on the fly - so it will allow you to enter anything, including rather long texts. It is not like `maxlength` property which just won't allow you to enter more than 100 characters.
2. You need some action to start validation. In most cases it is button, so just add it:

   `<asp:Button runat="server" Text="OK" />`
3. You need error message, which will be shown to user if validation fail - add `ErrorMessage` property to validator:

   `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ... ErrorMessage="ERROR!" />`

And that's it - type text, click button, see error.

If you do want to restrict text length on the fly - then you need JavaScript, you can see this question for samples [Specifying maxlength for multiline textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334286/specifying-maxlength-for-multiline-textbox)

Answer (score 1):

Use this JavaScript function for maxlength and call it on OnKeypress.

```
function checktextarea(textvalue,message,limit)
{
    var str="";
    var str=textvalue.value;
    if((str.length > limit ))
    {
        alert('Error : '+message + limit + ' characters\n'+ '          You entered text with Length '+str.length);
        textvalue.focus()
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks but i have said in my question : I do not want to use javascript solution !

Comment: use this regular expression "(\s|.){0,100}$"