# Catch when user inputs characters and change style

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a textbox in ASP.NET which when you click on the save button, the text will be saved in the database. In the database however, I specified a limit for the text which is 20 characters. I simply want to change the border color to red when the user writes more than 20 characters in this TextBox.
Anyway to do this without using javascript, instead use C#?

**Using ASP.NET Web Forms Web Site**

Comment: On blur event Ajax call to c# with text box value and on error change style to red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just put a max length of 20 characters on the textbox instead?  Then the user cannot enter more than 20 characters.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="20" />
```

or

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" MaxLength="20" />
```

Comment: Yes I ultimately did that...But I faced another problem which was with my Multiline textbox, it seems that `maxlentgh` doesn't work with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334286/specifying-maxlength-for-multiline-textbox  has a solution for working around multiline maxlength if you haven't seen it yet.

Answer (score 1):

> Anyway to do this without using javascript, instead use C#?

Only by doing a postback on every character. This is likely to make typing very hard: all those page refreshes are likely to cause characters to be lost.

JavaScript is definitely the right way to do something like this.

Comment: I think I have no choice but to use javascript...Can you please explain what I need to write please?

Comment: @Jack Look at the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event of the control in the DOM. You could use this event to change the CSS class of the control. There are plenty of examples of this kind of thing.